# Application is not working and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am new at android studio and here.

My application is not working at android emulator. It says application stopped. 
When I looked at android monitor, I saw that error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ads.firebase, PID: 4296
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzahj()Ljava/util/ArrayList;in class Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions' appears in /data/app/com.raykos.firebase-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes32.dex)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$3.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth$3.zzp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.addApi(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.initGoogleApiClient(CredentialsAPI.java:147)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.CredentialsAPI.<init>(CredentialsAPI.java:65)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.ChooseAccountActivity.onCreate(ChooseAccountActivity.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My build.grande is:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a version of FirebaseUI that is compatible with the other Firebase and Google Play libaries.  The [table of compatible versions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries) is included in the documentation.  In your case, you should use firebase-ui:1.1.1.

Also ensure that your emulator image includes a recent version of Google Play Services.  When running the emulated device, you can see the version of Google Play Services installed by going to Settings > Apps and selecting Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks you very much